# ffmpeg - create from .png -

Tags: ffmpeg, rstudio

I am new user to R studio.
I want to create a video from a serie of .png files.
I have checked the post about doing so but using the code provided result in error. I get the " unexpected token " error with command like :
ffmpeg -r 1/5 ...etc 
says " unexpected token 1 " ; ..then a bunch of other unexpected token...
What is wrong with the command line? Do I need to install a package to use this ffmpeg? If so, using the command " install.ffmpeg or install.package() didn't work.
Any help on this? thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be -framerate 1/5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Option -r doesn't understand 1/5. Here's an example:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```